# Puppet 2 invalid configurations w.r.t. Rubik's Cubes

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

My MoYu Puppet 2 has had a few small cubes disassembled and I've put them back more or less randomly. Specifically, I merely made sure that the resulting configuration remains solvable *as if* it was a classical Rubik's Cube (I used an app to ensure that). So:

- Knowing that this only happened to the small cubes, not the big corners, and the resulting configuration is valid for a 3x3 Rubik's Cube, am I guaranteed that I'll be able to solve the Puppet 2?
- More generally, is *any* valid configuration for a Rubik's Cube also valid for a Puppet 2? (Equivalently, is the number of configurations the same for both and is this merely a matter of the size of the formulas to obtain these configurations?)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange!  What is Puppet 2?

Comment: it is similar to a Rubik's cube except that corners are larger than sides, which makes some moves infeasible : https://cubezz.com/Buy-6321-MoYu+MeiLong+Puppet+Cube+Version+2+Stickerless.html